# How to add a selected value, taken from localStorage to the <select> element in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my .NET MVC project, I have an  element with three options. IDs for these three options are loaded from the DB.

When the page is loaded, I have an id, already stored in local storage.

I want to get the id from the local storage, and the option, which has that id a the value, needs to be selected automatically. In another word, prefilled.

I tried to access local storage inside the .cshtml file with C# code but seems like it doesn't work. Here is the tried code

```
@{ 
    var seletedId = localStorage.getItem('selectedID');
}
```

Here is my code for the  element

```
<select class="custom-select form-rounded" id="packageSelection">
   @foreach (var item in @Model.SubscriptionList)
   {
      <option 
        data-price=@item.Cost 
        value=@item.PaymentPricingId 
        selected="What should be added here?">@item.SubscriptionName</option>
   }
</select>
```

How can I solve this? Is there any workaround I can do for this? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use local storage in razor syntax like this

```
@{ 
    var seletedId = localStorage.getItem('selectedID');
}
```

You can simply use jQuery for this just put this **script** tag at the bottom of your page:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#packageSelection').val(localStorage.getItem("selectedID"));
    });
</script>
```

Also, remove **selected** attribute from `<option>` tag & don't forget to add jQuery reference in your page before this script tag.